# Tableau - How to make bar chart with bars of different widths

Tags: charts, width, tableau-api

Tableau Public, SQL, Excel. I have an up and down bar chart of about 30 customerIDs and how much they spent. ~3 big spenders, ~5 medium spenders, many small spenders. I want to make one bar chart with the three big spenders having fat bars, the 5 next spenders having medium thickness bars, the rest having very skinny bars. All on the same chart from the same excel sheet of data. Any way to do this? Tableau Public/SQL/Excel. Extra credit: any ways to make the bars different colors or maybe shaded in some way? Thank you so much in advance anon tech guru!!!! You're the best!!!
Example of what I mean: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jbAwfhx7hmgwNYWNaU5EOI8MLglEt6sE/view?usp=sharing

not sure what to do!

Answer (score 1):

Place your total $ on Size marks.

Or if you want to have them to be the same for each group, make a calculated field based on the cutoff desired and place that on size.

[image]

[image]